# switching views on a TabBar App

Tags: iphone

I am having a hell of a time trying to do what should be something simple.

I have created a Tab Bar Application. How do I change the view SomeView.xib ?

All the examples I see are from View To View, Tab to Nav.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

If the view you are trying to switch to has an accompanying view controller class then in the TabBarController.xib file click on the tab bar tab you want and go to the identity tab in the inspector and set the Class to the view controller that you want to display on that tab.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanx Mark

It helped. I dug into the NavigationController, found the specific NavController in there, set the class to the ViewController like you said. voilà!

Sorry about the late reply
ConfusedLemon

Comment: Hi, since my answer made it work, click on the checkmark next to it so others will know how to fix it.